# How to add and empty select list with Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I am trying to add a drop down select element to my .net page, but I need it to be black so I can populat it with a json list I have with jQuery. Right now, my view has this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Language", new SelectList(" "), "name = 'Laguange'", new { @class = "Language-List field form-group form-control" })
```

This 'works', but it seems to be confusing some stuff when I try to submit the form it is in. The value I select from it is never seen by the model, as it keeps triggering my `[Required]` validation helper.

Does anyone know How to add this without the `new SelectList(" ")` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest it's because youre using the name attribute in the wrong place.
Try this:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Language", new SelectList(" "), new {Name="Language", @class = "Language-List field form-group form-control" })
```

Notice the capital Name

Although as they are the same, you can just leave it out:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Language", new SelectList(" "), new {@class = "Language-List field form-group form-control" })
```

Comment: You mention that you're using jQuery, you should post that as well. As the .DropDownList() helper doesn't tie to a model, are you saying it 'triggers' the required attribute in your server side action when you post the form?